# Events using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue here is primarily jQuery...

I'm wanting to have events fire when a certain interaction is carried out however... only for "this" particular item provided all items are identical.

Firstly I'm not sure why the hover state is not firing - the console log shows the interaction is there however, not triggering the div to appear. I need the "show-me" div to appear when only hovered on the span and mouseoff for the div to disappear.

Also when the user clicks "select" for the options to ONLY hide for the current item input they selected - not all options to hide.

I'm having trouble trying to find a way to select elements that are somewhat out of scope as .find() will only find descendants - I want to have my mark up elsewhere and be able to select the element regardless of where it's location is within the markup.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RSapL/13/) of a working example for you to potentially "fiddle" with ;-)

All suggestions welcome!

**Here is my jQuery**

```
//Show item on hover for current item hovered
var item = $('.item'),
    itemShow = $('.show-me');

item.hover(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.show-me').show();
    console.log("hovered");
    }, function() { 
    $(this).nextAll('.show-me').hide();
});


//Click select to hide options 
$('.item').find('input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).nextAll('ul').hide();
    console.log("select was clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tree traversal is incorrect using `nextAll` which is for siblings.... use `find()` for descendents

```
$(this).find('.show-me').show();
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RSapL/14/)

Refer to [API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to charlie's answer, you may also use `.children()`,

```
$(this).children('.show-me').show();
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RSapL/17/)**